# Angular slicing an array of object

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, angular5

Am trying to get an array of object by slicing it from another array of object in angular 5. Am getting all the products from my API backend through a service. I passed the result to a property products of type array. i want to retrieve a section from the result i get. Okay might not be able to describe well with words so lemme drop the code.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
discountedproducts: Products[];
latestproducts: Products[];
 cheapestdeals: Products[];
randomproducts: Products[];

constructor(private productservice: ProductService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.productservice.getProductsBydiscount()
    .subscribe(res => this.discountedproducts = res);

    this.productservice.getProductsByNewest()
    .subscribe(res => this.latestproducts = res);

    this.productservice.getProductsByPrice()
    .subscribe(res => this.cheapestdeals = res);

    this.productservice.getProductsByRandom()
    .subscribe(res => this.randomproducts = res);
}

}
```

if i do something like

```
let slicedarray = latestproducts.slice(0, 3);
```

in the constructor it does not output anything when i try to display it using an ngFor loop. How can i do this better?

Comment: constructor < ngOnInit; construcotr executes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that on callback of `.subscribe` or else you will need to make `latestproducts` a subject and then subscribe to it.

```
this.productservice.getProductsByNewest()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.latestproducts = res;
      this.slicedArray = res.slice();
    }
);
```

And then do ngFor on `slicedArray`.